# Detecting liquid chemicals' level in a tank

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, arduino

I need to figure out how much liquid (insecticide) is left in a tank using Raspberri Pi.

I looked at infrared rangefinders but it looks like water absorbs IR and that won't work.

Next up - float switch. This would work except the tank is about 4ft in height and I'd like to know the level, not that it's "about to run out." In addition, I can't vouch for the insecticide not dissolving the float switch at some point. Maybe there's a float switch which reports the values progressively?

Is there a way to measure the weight of the water on top of some sensor?

Comment: Tank has to be sealed?

Comment: Infrared rangefinder detecting something that floats but doesn't absorb IR?

Comment: @MarkSetchell is there such a unit?

Comment: You could float something in the tank and point an optical or ultrasonic rangefinder to that. Other option: measure incoming and outgoing flows? Yet another: a pressure sensor at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ever I locate my previously purchased [eTape sensor](https://milonetech.com/products/chemical-etape-assembly), I'll be putting it service in a chlorine tank, which is a quite corrosive environment. The eTape sensor is teflon coated and rated for such use, so I suspect that insecticide would be an easy job for it.

Five to thirty two inch lengths (130 to 800 mm) puts the device close to your needs, with escalating prices to match, of course.

The circuit in which this device is to be used need only read as a voltage divider or a resistance option for US$30 more. In my correspondence with the manufacturer, I was cautioned to seal carefully the connections at the strip end, as they would not fare well when exposed to chlorine. Additionally, ordinary RTV silicone releases acetic acid when curing and would cause damage, but non-acetic acid type silicone would be acceptable.

With a 32 inch maximum length, you'd only know when you are nearing the last 16 inches. Reference is made in the page for custom lengths.

[image: eTape sensor]

As you've noted, expense for so many units would be prohibitive. I'll toss in an idea I had to reject due to corrosive vapor which might yet work for you.

A float on the surface with a panel similar in shape to the scale of the eTape extending through the top of the tank. This requires that there be head room equivalent to the depth of the liquid (Max Headroom?) to allow the scale to ride and fall with minimal resistance.

On the panel is a triangle, or if budget allows, two triangles. The width of the triangles match an optical sensor capacity. Black absorbs light, reducing the reflected light to the sensor. As the float rises, the black triangle increases (or decreases), changing the sensor figure. Two triangles would require two sensors and a bit of programming to calculate the position, but I believe the concept is sound.

If there is insufficient headroom, the float can drive a rack in place of the panel. The rack connects to a pinion on which is mounted a disk with a triangle on the perimeter of the disk.

Many years ago, I discovered an optical rotary encoder. It had four sensor pairs mounted along the radius of a transparent disk. The inner circle was half black and half clear. That sensor pair was a single bit in a binary read. The next outer circle was one-quarter black and one-quarter clear, making the second bit of the read. Each circle doubled the number of black/clear segments. With four sensors, 16 discreet figures could be collected. More sensors would mean more expense.

My previous suggestion of a rack driving a pinion would be more complex than ideal, I realize. The rack would have such a mechanical ratio as to spin the disk too many times or require a large diameter disk.

One could have a flexible tape with the triangle and sensor setup, with a take-up spool on a light spring, reducing headroom and slightly increasing complexity.

I realize also that you are likely looking for an off-the-shelf solution, rather than a homespun version as is formulating in my alleged mind.

Comment: Thanks. I've considered this. I'm thinking I'll need something less expensive as we have thousands of units to install. Any other ideas? I was thinking weighing the tank empty and then calculating the difference.

Comment: I like the weighing idea, although it seems expensive when referenced 1000x. I've thrown in another few concepts in the main post.

Comment: Have you considered using a weight sensor under the tank and connecting that to the RPi?  Being outside of the tank would be an advantage, but would probably require modifying the tank mount to add the sensor.